# Isn't an API or a wrapper a boundary in an application?

Tags: oop

The way the industry sees most software is that you need to have a SOLID framework to power up the behind-of-the-scenes, then you throw in an API (wrappers if you're lazy) over it and this is how actors from the outside interact with your framework.

> The boundary is responsible for translating model request/response into a format that the UI or actor can understand. They also mediate between model and lower levels, for example to manage database transactions.

This sounds to me like a boundary (be it object or anything else) is really a mediator between the inputs from the outside and what needs to happen with these inputs, as such, isn't it fair to say that an API is a boundary object on its own?

Comment: Shlaer and Mellor called it a bridge between domains. If you want to be a  purist, I suppose those are the terms you should use given they literally wrote the books on Object-Oriented Analysis and Design.